# My code is too long. It can be simplified?

Tags: c#

I have a little question about my code. I have two conditions and I would like to know if I can write this code simpler and shorter using a method or something.

```
 if (CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock() % 2 == 0)
    {
        Clothes[askedCoatRandom.getRandom()].setCurrentChildIndex(CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock() + 1);
        CoatRandom.randomRule.addBlock(CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock() + 1);
        badCoatRandom.randomRule.addBlock(CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock() + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        Clothes[askedCoatRandom.getRandom()].setCurrentChildIndex(CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock() - 1);
        CoatRandom.randomRule.addBlock(CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock() - 1);
        badCoatRandom.randomRule.addBlock(CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock() - 1);
    }
```

Comment: both conditions do the same, only one adds and another decreases

Comment: Seems like a [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The only difference is `-1` or `+1`. Just set a variable to `-1` or `1` and add that instead. For example: `int v = CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock() % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1`

Comment: You are calling 7 times the same method. What about getting its result just one time and use it to replace the 7 calls?

Answer (score 5):

```
    int lastBlock = CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock();            
    lastBlock = lastBlock % 2 == 0 ? lastBlock + 1 : lastBlock - 1;

    Clothes[askedCoatRandom.getRandom()].setCurrentChildIndex(lastBlock);
    CoatRandom.randomRule.addBlock(lastBlock);
    badCoatRandom.randomRule.addBlock(lastBlock);
```

Comment: Nice +1; however, we should assume that `CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock()` returns the *same value* (i.e. doesn't contain, say `Random.NextValue` or alike) and *can be cached*.

Comment: Yes, good note, but if it returns different value with every call, I even can't imagine that kind of BS happens in this code :)

Answer (score 3):

You can *combine* both conditions:

```
int shift = CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock() % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1;
Clothes[askedCoatRandom.getRandom()].setCurrentChildIndex(CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock() + shift);
CoatRandom.randomRule.addBlock(CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock() + shift);
badCoatRandom.randomRule.addBlock(CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock() + shift);
```

If `CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock()` returns the *same* value each time it called it can be *cached*:

```
var index = CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock() + 
           (CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock() % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1);

Clothes[askedCoatRandom.getRandom()].setCurrentChildIndex(index);
CoatRandom.randomRule.addBlock(index);
badCoatRandom.randomRule.addBlock(index);
```

Comment: yes, perfect, that's what I wanted, thanks a lot

Comment: what about to remember CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock() to separate variable then operate with it and to not call method few times?

Comment: @HimBromBeere: I'm sorry, but I can't see the problem: `var index = CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock() + (CoatRandom.randomRule.getLastBlock() % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1);` is `Last Block` plus `shift`